# fastest way to compare two data tables cell by cell

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have two huge data tables with 300 columns and 100000 rows in both.I want to compare them cell by cell and show the result in a third data table. If match has occurred show 1 in result and if miss match happened show 0 in result.I used for loop but it was very slow and took a lot of time.can any one help please?

Comment: You need to provide more details about your question, your current code and your expected result

Answer (score 2):

you can follow the below link : -

http://canlu.blogspot.in/2009/05/how-to-compare-two-datatables-in-adonet.html

https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-compare-rows

The only possible solution is the looping , but the above two links gives you some built-in collections that may ease the looping and give you performance .

Comment: I want to compare cell by cell not row by row

Comment: @sh.h What's the difference?  btw, the canlu link above was excellent

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to provide some code and same expectation.

2. if you have a table with 300 columns I think you broke some fundamental normalization database design role.
3. if you want the result as t1.c1 = t2.c2 ... you can try to perform this in query with join as more performant way then loop through every columns for every rows